# Why Google Nearby Connections needs ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and/or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, google-nearby

I googled very hard and still no explanations "why?" these permissions are needed to establish **offline**(no internet) connection between devices. I have simple app that requires only p2p-star strategy to exchange data between devices in master-slave pattern and I have troubles explaining to my users why my app needs them. "Just because lib said so. That's why".

Official documentation also said nothing to me.

*"A primary goal of this API is to provide a platform that is simple, reliable, and performant. Under the hood, the **API uses a combination of Bluetooth, BLE, and Wifi hotspots**, leveraging the strengths of each while circumventing their respective weaknesses. This effectively abstracts the vagaries of Bluetooth and Wifi across a range of Android OS versions and hardware, allowing developers to focus on the features that matter to their users."*

PS: as I know ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION are about GPS

PSS: in case this question will be answered here
https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/issues/204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Bluetooth and WiFi scans can reveal the user's location, either as an approximation ("Family Room TV" was discovered, so you must be home) or in detail (Device A, B, and C were last seen at lat/lng X, so we think you're probably at X).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le#permissions

Comment: Thanks dude, I didn't even think about looking for at that direction.

Comment: Is it still valid with Android 12 and new Bluetooth permissions?
"Android 12 introduces the BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permissions. These permissions make it easier for apps that target Android 12 to interact with Bluetooth devices, especially for apps that don't require access to device location."

Comment: Not yet, but there's a Play Services update launching in December to handle that (internally named v2.3). If your app targets Android S, is running on Android S, and has added 'neverForLocation' in the AndroidManifest, you will only need BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT. You will no longer need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.